# Ubuntu nginx container 403 forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

I've build an ubuntu container with nginx websever. The docker file looks as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER James Turnbull "james@example.com"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2014-06-01
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/website
ADD nginx/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

The file structure looks as follow:

```
xxxxxx@xxxxx:~/sample$ ls
Dockerfile  nginx  website
```

After running the container with the statement:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80 --name website \-v $PWD\website:/var/www/html/website \kostonstyle/nginx nginx
```

The nginx server works as expected but when I request for a webpage, I've got only

```
curl 0.0.0.0:32769
<html>
  <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your folder `website` permissions in container. And chown it to `www-data`

Comment: Not sure why did you curl port 32769 ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the Dockerfile you built is part of the documentation, but basically just for illustrational purposes. There's various things not properly setup in that example (for example, correct *logging* for docker). It's better to use the [official NGINX](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) images as a base-image, because those are actively maintained, smaller, and properly setup for docker (e.g. https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a8b6da8425c4a41a5dedb1fb52e429232a55ad41/Dockerfile#L14-L18)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 403 error can be the result of serving an empty directory, and directory-listing disabled (the default). See [resolving 403 errors](http://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/) for some hints on how to resolve this.

If the website directory does not contain an `index.html`, add this file

If the website directory *does* contain an `index.html`, it's possible that the volume is not mounted correctly. If you're using boot2docker, make sure that your website directory is underneath the `c:\users` (Windows) or `/Users` (OS X) directory, because only those directories are accessible by docker (by default)

Answer (score 0):

As an additional comment to thaJeztah's answer, note that the mapping on Windows is case sensitive, so if you wish to map to a 'Sites' folder under your 'c:\users' dir then you'll need to specify the mapping with the right casing:

```
docker run --name website -p 80 -d -v /c/Users/username/Sites:/var/www/html/website nginx
```

(I would post as a comment on thaJeztah's answer but I don't have enough rep yet!)